# Gitlab pipeline - datetime output issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to get the aws secret manager - describe_secrets through Gitlab pipeline.

When I try the command using the aws cli, I am getting the output like below (Datetime format is ok)

`aws secretsmanager describe-secret --secret-id ${SECRET_NAME} --region ${DEFAULT_REGION} --output text --query [LastChangedDate,LastRotatedDate]`

The output is
`2022-07-12T00:21:01.907000-07:00        2022-07-12T00:21:01.939000-07:00`

When I run the same command through gitlab pipeline, I am getting the output below (Probably relative value).

```
1657610461.907  1657610461.939
```

Could someone please assit me to get the same format as aws cli. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you compare aws cli version and check image(or try different image) in pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation:

> By default, the AWS CLI version 2 translates all response DateTime values to ISO 8601 format.

If you're seeing epoch timestamps, it's because you're either using AWS CLI version 1 or have requested this format through your CLI configuration.

For AWS CLI v1, you can opt into ISO 8601 display format by setting the `cli_timestamp_format` in your [profile settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html?highlight=format) (e.g., `~/.aws/config`) to `iso8601` For example:

```
[default]
cli_timestamp_format = iso8601
```

Alternatively, you should make sure your job is using AWS CLI v2 and it will use this format by default.